# no error output but build failed when using xelatex under linux

Tags: xetex

when I checkout this project https://github.com/ustctug/ustcthesis.git and use xelatex to build the project in linux:

```
xelatex main.tex
```

there is no error output and no pdf generate. the output look like this:

```
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
Package caption Info: longtable package is loaded.
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty
Package: ltcaption 2021/01/08 v1.4c longtable captions (AR)
)
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/XITSMath-Regular(1)/m/n --> TU/texgyretermes(0)/m/n
on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/texgyretermes(0)/m/it on input line
 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/texgyretermes(0)/b/n on input line
15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/texgyreheros(0)/m/n on input line 1
5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/texgyreheros(0)/b/n on input line
15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/texgyrecursor(0)/m/n on input line
15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/texgyrecursor(0)/b/n on input line
15.

(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-diction
ary-english.trsl
File: translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `tra
nslations-basic-dictionary')
)
Package translations Info: loading dictionary `translations-basic-dictionary' f
or `english'. on input line 15.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 15.
 (./main.out) (./main.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `main.out'.



Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

*geometry* verbose mode - [ newgeometry ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.2698pt, 452.96826pt, 72.2698pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.2698pt, 700.50723pt, 72.2698pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=452.96826pt
* \textheight=700.50723pt
* \oddsidemargin=-0.00018pt
* \evensidemargin=-0.00018pt
* \topmargin=-29.59084pt
* \headheight=21.33955pt
* \headsep=8.2511pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=22.47748pt
* \marginparwidth=88.0pt
* \marginparsep=7.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FandolFang(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'FandolFang' with options
(fontspec)             [Extension={.otf},UprightFont={*-Regular}].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[FandolFang-Regular.otf]/OT:language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:

File: figures/ustc-name.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use figures/ustc-name.pdf>

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Noto Sans CJK SC Medium/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Noto Sans CJK SC/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSansCJKSC(0)' created for font 'Noto
(fontspec)             Sans CJK SC' with options [Script={CJK},BoldFont={*
(fontspec)             Medium}].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Noto Sans CJK
(fontspec)             SC/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Noto Sans CJK SC
(fontspec)             Medium/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Noto Sans
(fontspec)             CJK SC/BI/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:

File: figures/ustc-badge.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use figures/ustc-badge.pdf>
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 16.0617pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 14.05399pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.54048pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 16.05827pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 14.05098pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53824pt on input line 18.
[1



] [2

]
File: figures/ustc-badge.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use figures/ustc-badge.pdf>
 [3] [4

]
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.04628pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.03471pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.22777pt on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/XITSMath-Regular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 12.0437pt on input line 18.
```

in my macbook pro the build success, but not work under linux. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: That isn't the complete output unless it just crashed, but then Linux would tell you. What's in the log?

Comment: as cfr says, the log can not end that way unless something killed the tex job.add \tracingall somewhere not in a group but after page 4, and try again

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that linux killed the process because the oom using this command:

```
dmesg |grep -v "destination"
```

this is the output:

```
[570564.172295] Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod497b66ba_3205_4535_909e_0b87fc592a85.slice/cri-containerd-fcc91dd58ce9f044b8f90e751fbd1f8190c9ab2337991612b7b59d1aab62d4ac.scope: cache:0KB rss:36KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:36KB inactive_file:0KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
[570564.172305] Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod497b66ba_3205_4535_909e_0b87fc592a85.slice/cri-containerd-e267c0337ba690e906100fbf5507e7850712bf87180d74650f2de118d85b437d.scope: cache:9100KB rss:277584KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:120KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:277584KB inactive_file:4616KB active_file:4476KB unevictable:0KB
[570564.172314] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
[570564.172516] [22257] 65535 22257      239        1       3        0          -998 pause
[570564.172520] [24974]     0 24974     5829      643      15        0           999 cv-render
[570564.172531] [27143]     0 27143      424      149       5        0           999 sh
[570564.172541] [31648]     0 31648   839872    63837     465        0           999 xelatex
[570564.172544] [32131]     0 32131     6263     5872      17        0           999 xdvipdfmx
[570564.172547] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 31648 (xelatex) score 1886 or sacrifice child
[570564.173802] Killed process 32131 (xdvipdfmx), UID 0, total-vm:25052kB, anon-rss:22996kB, file-rss:492kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Comment: you can run using xelatex --no-pdf so it does not call xdvipdfmx, that should let xetex finish cleanly and you can check a full log for errors or loops or whatever. then you can try running xdvipdfmx yourfile.xdv  to generate the pdf, see if that runs out of memory when run in isolation.